# Generating subsets of set. Laziness?

Tags: haskell

I have written a function generating subsets of subset. It caused stack overflow when I use in the following way `subsets [1..]`. And it is "normal" behaviour when it comes to "normal" (no-lazy) languages. And now, I would like to improve my function to be lazy.

P.S. I don't understand laziness ( And I try to understand it) so perhaps my problem is strange for you- please explain. :)

P.S. 2 Feel free to say me something about my disability in Haskell ;)

```
subsets :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets (x:xs) = (map (\ e -> x:e) (subsets xs)) ++ (subsets xs)
subsets [] = [[]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two problems with that function. First, it recurses *twice*, which makes it exponentially more ineffiecient than necessary (if we disregard the exponential number of results...), because each subtree is recalculated every time for all overlapping subsets; this can be fixed by `let`ing the recursive call be the same value:

```
subsets' :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets' [] = [[]]
subsets' (x:xs) = let s = subsets' xs
                  in map (x:) s ++ s
```

This will already allow you to calculate `length $ subsets' [1..25]` in a few seconds, while `length $ subsets [1..25]` takes... well, I didn't wait ;)

The other issue is that with your version, when you give it an infinite list, it will recurse on the *infinite tail* of that list first. To generate all finite subsets in a meaningful way, we need to ensure two things: first, we must build up each set from smaller sets (to ensure termination), and second, we should ensure a *fair* order (ie., not generate the list `[[1], [2], ...]` first and never get to the rest). For this, we start from `[[]]` and recursively add the current element to everything we have already generated, and then remember the new list for the next step:

```
subsets'' :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets'' l = [[]] ++ subs [[]] l
  where subs previous (x:xs) = let next = map (x:) previous
                               in next ++ subs (previous ++ next) xs
        subs _ [] = []
```

Which results in this order:

```
*Main> take 100 $ subsets'' [1..]
[[],[1],[2],[2,1],[3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,2,1],[4],[4,1],[4,2],[4,2,1],[4,3],[4,3,1],[4,3,2],[4,3,2,1],[5],[5,1],[5,2],[5,2,1],[5,3],[5,3,1],[5,3,2],[5,3,2,1],[5,4],[5,4,1],[5,4,2],[5,4,2,1],[5,4,3],[5,4,3,1],[5,4,3,2],[5,4,3,2,1],[6],[6,1],[6,2],[6,2,1],[6,3],[6,3,1],[6,3,2],[6,3,2,1],[6,4],[6,4,1],[6,4,2],[6,4,2,1],[6,4,3],[6,4,3,1],[6,4,3,2],[6,4,3,2,1],[6,5],[6,5,1],[6,5,2],[6,5,2,1],[6,5,3],[6,5,3,1],[6,5,3,2],[6,5,3,2,1],[6,5,4],[6,5,4,1],[6,5,4,2],[6,5,4,2,1],[6,5,4,3],[6,5,4,3,1],[6,5,4,3,2],[6,5,4,3,2,1],[7],[7,1],[7,2],[7,2,1],[7,3],[7,3,1],[7,3,2],[7,3,2,1],[7,4],[7,4,1],[7,4,2],[7,4,2,1],[7,4,3],[7,4,3,1],[7,4,3,2],[7,4,3,2,1],[7,5],[7,5,1],[7,5,2],[7,5,2,1],[7,5,3],[7,5,3,1],[7,5,3,2],[7,5,3,2,1],[7,5,4],[7,5,4,1],[7,5,4,2],[7,5,4,2,1],[7,5,4,3],[7,5,4,3,1],[7,5,4,3,2],[7,5,4,3,2,1],[7,6],[7,6,1],[7,6,2],[7,6,2,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot! It is a solution with monads. What about without them?

Comment: @Gilgamesz turns out the monad is not even needed. The previous version was wrong anyway -- now it works with plain lists, and hopefully correctly.

Comment: @Gilgamesz Laziness is one of the core, yet most advanced topics of Haskell. For example, phg's first point is a result of Haskell's specific implementation of laziness, which uses a graph structure to represent evaluations in progress: IIRC, in some limited cases, the complier *will* catch the duplication, and share the same data structure in both instances --- but not always. This is one of the prices we pay for having laziness. It's a limitation of the compiler that we must be aware of when focusing on performance, or dealing with infinity.

Comment: Good point. Specifically, it helps much to think about the language from the perspective of [graph reduction](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/PAGES/207.HTM).

Answer (score 3):

You can't generate *all* the subsets of an infinite set: they form an uncountable set. Cardinality makes it impossible.

At most, you can try to generate all the *finite* subsets. For that, you can't proceed by induction, from `[]` onwards, since you'll never reach `[]`. You need to proceed inductively from the beginning of the list, instead of the end.

Comment: ok, you are right. You recall me some facts from set theory :D. Ok, so let's consider only finite sets. How to improve my function to be lazy?

Answer (score 3):

A right fold solution would be:

```
powerset :: Foldable t => t a -> [[a]]
powerset xs = []: foldr go (const []) xs [[]]
    where go x f a = let b = (x:) <$> a in b ++ f (a ++ b)
```

then:

```
\> take 8 $ powerset [1..]
[[],[1],[2],[2,1],[3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Comment: +1 for brevity, but it needs more explanation. Especially since it uses the not-quite-idiomatic technique "calling `foldr` with *four* arguments", which can easily confuse newcomers. I'd still prefer plain recursion, which I find more readable.

Comment: @chi compared to the recursive solution, this uses less memory and performs faster! try `length $ powerset [1..24]` with `ghc --make -O2` on this solution versus the recursive one.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But if you can explain in some words your solution it will be great. Especiall I do not understand `(const [])` and `<$>` :)

Comment: @Gilgamesz [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#const) is simply defined as `const x _ = x`, that is it just returns its 1st argument ignoring the 2nd one. `(x:) <$> a` in here is equivalent to `map (x:) a`.

Comment: Thanks you again. I'll analyze it tomorrow - I am too exhausted today. If I have a probleam I will response here.

Comment: @behzad.nouri That is very neat. Does anybody know why this ends up perfoming better? Because after inlining `foldr` and some currying, it is exactly the same as my second version, just with the arguments of `subs`/`go` reversed.